# Issue with Itextsharp in c# asp.net server. Cannot load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am making a webpage with c# code running in the back. I am using the itextsharp library to search through PDF files. I am able to compile and deploy the code because I did add the .dll reference and added the required using statements to import the .dll. But in run-time i get this error message:

Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Stacktrace:    at PDF_Document_Gallery.VisualWebPart1.PDF_Document_Gallery.ReadPdfFile(String fileName)
   at PDF_Document_Gallery.VisualWebPart1.PDF_Document_Gallery.keyword_and_content_search(String result)

Does anyone know whats wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Look at the location you deployed to, is the itextsharp assembly there?

Comment: How do I check the location? Its a microsoft sharepoint 2010 environment. Can I not just embed the dll into the visual studio 2010 project so that it doesn't need to be added anywhere else?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865969/sharepoint-webpart-include-additional-assembly-in-wsp-package

Comment: Im using VS2010 and I can't find the property Copy Local, where is it?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx